# Can html file picker dialog be customized?

Tags: html, css

This is what happens when `click` event is triggered on `<input type='file'/>` HTML element on Chrome, MacOS:

[image]

Can this dialog be customized beyond `accept` attribute which sets accepted file types? E.g., can "Open" label (bottom-right) be changed to "Upload"?

Comment: No, that's an OS level dialog that the browser can't change

Comment: Can you put the code you've tried?

Comment: Simply, no. You can't do that.

Comment: Thanks. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept! :)